# Integral with unknown function in integrand

Tags: calculus, limits

I have the following problem from an aerodynamics book:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\gamma(\theta)\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)-\cos(\theta_0)}d\theta=2\pi v_{\infty}\alpha$$

The goal is to find $\gamma(\theta)$ with $\gamma(\theta\to \pi)=0$. $\theta_0$, $v_{\infty}$ and $\alpha$ are known. The book gives the result

$\gamma(\theta)=2\alpha v_{\infty}\frac{1+\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}$.

I am very interested in the method how this was derived.

Comment: Equation that you have is a Fredholm integral equation of the first kind with degenerated kernel

Comment: @KostiantynLapchevskyi: No need for that, the solution is much simpler, as my answer shows.

Comment: @AlexM.: you are right, nice answer. Still, I think such reference is needed for the sake of completeness, e.g. if OP would like to check whether solution is unique

Comment: @KostiantynLapchevskyi: I am curious, how would you attack the problem of uniqueness? I tried to set $\gamma = 2 \alpha v_\infty \frac {1+ \cos \theta} {\sin \theta} + h$, with $h$ orthogonal to $\frac {1+ \cos \theta} {\sin \theta}$ in $L^2([0,\pi])$ and $h(\pi) = 0$, and then I tried to attack with with techniques of Fourier analysis (extended to the problem to $[-\pi, \pi]$ with $h$ odd, wrote it as $\sum b_n \sin nx$) - to no avail, though. It seems to me that the solution is not necessarily unique.

Comment: @AlexM.: As I see we can use following properties: for Volterra equation of the first kind $\int_a^x K(x,t)y(t)dt=f(x)$ ($a\le x\le b$) exists unique solution if $f(x)$, $K(x,t)$ and their first derivatives are continuous on $[a,b]$ and $S=\{a \le x \le b, a \le t \le b\}$ and also $K(x,x) \ne 0$, $f(a)=0$. We can think about Volterra eq. of the first kind as about Fredholm eq. of the first kind with kernel $K(x,t)=0$ for $t>x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is quite easy in fact. First, let $\gamma (\theta) = 2 \alpha v_\infty f (\theta)$, so that your equation becomes

$$\int \limits _0 ^\pi f(\theta) \frac {\sin \theta} {\cos \theta - \cos \theta_0} \Bbb d \theta = \pi .$$

Notice that $\pi$ on the right hand side is exactly the length of the integration interval, so you just have to choose $f$ in order to make the whole integrand $1$, which means that

$$f = \frac {\cos \theta - \cos \theta_0} {\sin \theta} .$$

Putting the constants back, we get

$$\gamma (\theta) = 2 \alpha v_\infty \frac {\cos \theta - \cos \theta_0} {\sin \theta} : (0, \pi) \to \Bbb R .$$

(The interval is open at both ends in order for the fraction to be defined.)

Finally, it seems that you have misunderstood the statement in the book: you are also required to find $\theta_0$ such that $\lim \limits _{\theta \to \pi} \gamma (\theta) = 0$. Notice that for $\theta \to \pi$, the numerator of $\gamma$ tends to $\cos \pi - \cos \theta_0$, while the denominator tends to $0$. It becomes necessary, then, to choose $\theta_0$ such that $\cos \pi - \cos \theta_0 = 0$, which means that $\theta_0 \in (2 \Bbb Z + 1) \pi$. Let us show that this is also sufficient: if $\theta_0 \in (2 \Bbb Z + 1) \pi$, then

$$\lim \limits _{\theta \to \pi} \gamma (\theta) = \lim \limits _{\theta \to \pi} 2 \alpha v_\infty \frac {\cos \theta + 1} {\sin \theta} = \left[ \frac 0 0 \text{, so apply L'Hospital's theorem}\right] = \\
\lim \limits _{\theta \to \pi} 2 \alpha v_\infty \frac {-\sin \theta} {\cos \theta} = -2 \alpha v_\infty \tan \pi = 0 ,$$

therefore the condition $\theta_0 \in (2 \Bbb Z + 1) \pi$ is also sufficient in order to obtain $\lim \limits _{\theta \to \pi} \gamma (\theta) = 0$.

To conclude, it is necessary and sufficient to have $\theta_0 \in (2 \Bbb Z + 1) \pi$, in which case

$$\gamma (\theta) = 2 \alpha v_\infty \frac {\cos \theta + 1} {\sin \theta} ,$$

precisely as stated in the book. This allows us te extend $\gamma$ by continuity to the whole interval $[0, \pi]$ by defining it to be $0$ in $0$ and $\pi$.

Notice that the solution is not necessarily unique.